# Which type of DVI cable will connect the 9400GT with this display?

Tags: dvi, nvidia-geforce

I am going to buy [BenQ G2220HD 22" LCD display](http://benq.com/products/LCD/?product=1458&page=specifications).

I already have an XFX [GeForce 9400GT](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_9400gt_us.html).

Both support DVI. But the confusion came when I wanted to actually buy a DVI cable.

I got confused with DVI, DVI-D and DVI-I and then Single link and Dual link!

Can someone tell me whether [this cable](http://www.theitdepot.com/details-Bafo+RA-DVI-SL-2M-V1+DVI-D+Single+Link+Cable_C4P3756.html) can be used to connect my 9400GT to my BenQ display? If not, what kind of DVI cable should I buy - DVI, DVI-D, single link, dual link, DVI-I??

Basically, GeForce website says the card's output is Dual Link DVI. The BenQ website says the monitor takes input as DVI-D. What are my options now? What kind of DVI cable should I get? Please don't suggest brands because from experience I know that most of them won't be available here in India. Can you please just tell me the TYPE of DVI cable I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DVI-D is what most monitors take - it is the pure digital signal.

DVI-A is just the analogue signals, as would be found on VGA' d-stub connector. This is rarely seen.

DVI-I carries both the digital and analogue signals. This is what most video cards output, so you can either connect the output port directly to a DVI-D or DVI-I port on a monitor or through an adaptor to a VGA port on a monitor that has no DVI input. Monitors that expect DVI-D will accept a DVI-I cable - they'll just ignore the signals on the extra pins.

Single-link DVI has enough signalling bandwidth to support a 1920*1200 display at 60Hz so usually isn't required for home arrangements with LCD screens (60Hz is usually fine for LCD displays, unlike CRTs, and displays with resolutions above 1920*1200 are unlikely to be found outside specialist areas). Most modern graphics cards support dual-link though, in case you want to run at a resolution and refresh rate that requires it. As with DVI-D/DVI-I, the extra pins for dual-link output should simply be ignored if present but the monitor does not need/support them.

**Edit**: so in summary, that monitor+card+cable *should* work fine together. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVI-D#Connector for more detail.

Comment: A single link cable can be used to connect devices that are capable of delivering dual link data - only some of the data will not flow through but its enough to run 1920*1200. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, both devices will see the missing pins as meaning they are talking to a single-link device, and will limit their capabilities accordingly (only sending/expecting data down the one set of lines and refusing to move to a mode that would require the extra bandwidth).

Comment: These days, DVI-A is mostly used for cables that have a VGA connector at one end and a DVI connector at the other.  Cables of this type are quite useful for laptops and (occasionally) plugging old monitors into machines without a VGA port.

Answer (score 1):

Video cards today output both analog and digital signal in the DVI connector thus you can use any type of cable that is suitable for your monitor. Usually monitors with a DVI connector will take the digital signal (DVI-D), while those taking analog signal are likely to use a D-sub (AKA VGA) connector.

I have two monitors, Benq G2220HDA 21.5" and Philips 170S 17". Both accept analog signals, however, I use DVI-I dual link cables exclusively, since this allows me to replace the monitor without hunting for a cable. I simply use a cheap DVI -> VGA converter at the back of the monitor.

Here is a picture of the various DVI connectors. The second from the top (DVI-I dual link) is what the video cards have on the back and will work with any cable. You should get a cable with that connector, as it will work with any monitor, be it digital or analog, single or double link.

[image: Image of DVI connectors]